# How to configure IE Driver in robotftamework to support proxy configuration

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

My application under test is behind a proxy server. I want to run test using robotFramework and Selenium2Library on IE Browser. It works on FF browser but not IE.
In fact the confiuration that I have used for FF Browser is shown below

```
${proxy}       Evaluate sys.modules['selenium.webdriver']   sys, selenium.webdriver                                     
${proxy.ssl_proxy}  Set Variable    @proxy:8080                     
${proxy.http_proxy} Set Variable    @proxy:8080                     
Create Webdriver    Firefox proxy=${proxy}
```

I tried to use the same configuration for IE Browser but it show this error

```
FAIL : TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

When IE driver name is `ie`

```
FAIL : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'
```

When IE driver name is `Ie`

So, I have tried to use other options such:

```
Open Browser    ${base_url} ${browser}  desired_capabilities=httpProxy:@proxy:8080,sslProxy:@proxy:8080
```

But it did only open the browser.

Comment: I think we need more information than just "not works". Do you get any errors? How are you opening the browser?

Comment: You are missing a space after the word `Firefox` on the last line. Though, you say the problem is with Ie so can you show us the code you're using for Ie? Also, can you show us the code that gives you the "unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'" error?  Without seeing the actual code and the actual error, all we can do is guess. Also, what version of the IE driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact I have just noticed something. It'a about network. I can connect to IE driver and open browser with proxy configuration when I'm connected to the internet. But, when I'm working in the private network of the company , I can't connect to IE driver. It's a little bit weird.

Comment: For IE I'm using :  ${proxy}= Create List htmlProxy=@proxy:8080 sslProxy=@proxy:8080      
Create Webdriver Ie             proxy=${proxy}

Comment: I have this error message when I connected to the provate network of the company Setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the IEDriver'

Comment: Try "Set Environmental Variable  no_proxy  127.0.0.1" before Create Webdriver. You are getting error because the Selenium traffic is getting sent to the proxy server set in Internet Options.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I think that Selenium2Library doesn't support Set Environmental Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the problem related To IEDriver when the application under test is behind proxy server. In fact, i used the wrong version of IEDriverServer. This was the main problem

For testers who will face the same problem, below are the steps:

1. With Internet Explorer and Even Google Chrome you don't need to use `Create WebDriver`, `Open Browser` is useful for example `Open Browser  ${base_url}   ie`
2. You have to download `The Internet Explorer Driver Server`from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
3. Set in your system path the path of `The Internet Explorer Driver Server`
4. Configure your IE browser with the server proxy host and port number

Enjoy testing :)

I am available for further informations

Comment: Can you pls explain the step3 and 4 in detail?

Comment: Step 3: you can refer to this link  : How to set the path and environment variables in Windows http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm Step 4 : In internet Option in your browser configure the IP address and the port number of your proxy

Comment: Thanks for the link . Anyhow i managed to get it work by placing the `web driver` in the path of  my test cases

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.5, Selenium2Library has a keyword named [Create Webdriver](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Create%20Webdriver) which can be used instead of Open Browser. Create Webdriver lets you configure a proxy.

Comment: Yes i'm using Create Webdriver. In fact, it works with FF browser but not with IE

Comment: @Imen What version of IE? IE started to support pure `WebDriver` just in recent releases of IE11.

Comment: I have worked with Selenium WebDriver/Junit with IE8 and t works very well. Now , i want to use IE10 with Selenium2Library and robotframework.